# How would I automate converting Discord User IDs to usernames?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a list of user IDs in a text file, separated by spaces. I want to make something that converts all these IDs to usernames/discriminators (e.g. 1234567890 = user#1234).

```
import discord
import asyncio


 
client = discord.Client()

people = open("people.txt", "r")
lines = people.read().split(' ')
        

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord')

    for id in lines:
        user = await client.get_user(id)
        print(user.name)
  

people.close()

client.run("token")
```

This code here gives me an error:

```
 File "main.py", line 19, in on_ready
    user = await client.get_user(id)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```py
user = await client.fetch_user(id)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't accept this answer yet because of the time limit but it helped.

Comment: @evejohnson .